# Restore missing or deleted calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

Working with one of my Google Apps users and a shared calendar he create suddenly disappeared.  It was hidden (first thing we checked), but just gone.  It is a number of steps to delete a calendar (for safety reasons) and it was certainly not deleted in this fashion.

Using the Google APIs Explorer for Calendar API v3 we do see a deleted calendar using calendar.calendarList.list when showDeleted is true.  If we highlight that item in the JSON response the dropdown arrow on the top right of the item shows it can be used in calendar.calendarList.patch.  Trying to remove the "deleted" flag results in a 404 resource not found.  Copied the calendarId from the Patch JSON body up to the calendarId box, fields editor to show most all fields.  Trying the same for calendar.calendars.patch we get the same result.

The OAuth scope is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.  JSON body is

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry",
 "etag": "\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\"",
 "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com",
 "defaultReminders": [
 ],
 "deleted": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a calendar is deleted from the `CalendarList` but you still know the `id`, you can add it back to the list with the [`insert`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert) endpoint.

Comment: Still get the Resource was not found error, tried using the @group.calendar.google.com on the id and without it.

    POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users /me/calendarList?colorRgbFormat=true&fields=deleted%2Cdescription%2Cetag%2Chidden%2Cid&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
 
  {
   "id": "xxxxxxxx@@group.calendar.google.com"
  }